# How do i conditionally change the parameter of an angular filter

Tags: angularjs, ternary-operator, angularjs-filter

I have a custom angular filter, ellipsesFilter, that I use for truncating and adding an ellipses to words that are too long to fit in a particular table.

Like this:

```
<div>{{app.firstLastName | ellipsesFilter:13 }}</div>
```

However, if `app.flag` is `true` we add another word to the end of firstLastName. If that's the case, then I want the ellipses filter param to be different. Ideally, something like this

```
{{app.firstLastName | app.flag? : ellipsesFilter:10 : ellipsesFilter:13}}
```

I've tried various ways of doing this, none have worked.  Anyone know how?

Comment: How about passing an array of values into `ellipsesFilter` and adjusting the contents of that array?

Comment: @Oliver how would i adjust the contents of the array inline based on that boolean value?

Comment: You wouldn't. You would do that in a controller. Otherwise it could get a bit messy. Sadly, I have no simple example code at hand where I know that it will work for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.. you actually can use the ternary operator to switch the parameter value like this:

```
{{name | ellipsesFilter:flag ? 10 : 13}}
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/zWsNk1VzVgBZeoGb5NCP

Answer (score 1):

You can use a value on scope ?

```
<div>{{app.firstLastName | ellipsesFilter:lengthToFilter }}</div>
//js
$scope.lengthToFilter =  $scope.app.flag? 13:10
```

---

Its also smart enough to accept a function:

```
<div>{{app.firstLastName | ellipsesFilter:getLengthToFilter() }}</div>   
//js
$scope.getLengthToFilter = function(){
      return $scope.app.flag? 13:10 ;
}
```